# Trying to script deleting files from wildcards in a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to script deleting files whose filenames match wildcards in a text file.

I'm using the following

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo -e "Usage: $(basename $0) FILE\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
    echo -e "$1: File doesn't exist.\n"
    exit 1
fi

while read -r line; do
    [ -n "$line" ] && rm -- "$line"
done < "$1"
```

in the file `list` there are lines

```
file*
test*
```

I get the following if i run this

```
rm: cannot remove ‘file*’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘test*’: No such file or directory
```

I think the * isn't accepted to delete files such as

```
file 1
file2
file2.txt
test 001 more teskt.txt
```

Sorry I'm no linux expert. Maybe someone has an easy answer, maybe replace the * with something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pathname expansion happens after variable expansion, but only on unquoted parts of the command line.

```
rm -- $line  # <- no double quotes to expand wildcards
```

This wouldn't work for filenames containing spaces, as word splitting also happens after variable expansion.

You can use Perl to expand globs:

```
perl -lne 'unlink glob' -- list.txt
```

Normal [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) needs whitespace backslashed, but you can switch to [File::Glob](http://p3rl.org/File::Glob) for a different behaviour if it's more convenient to you:

```
perl -MFile::Glob=:bsd_glob -lne 'unlink glob' -- list.txt
```

Comment: To clarify, this won't work as expected if `$line` contains spaces, but it will still delete filenames that contain spaces. By the way, is there a way to do pathname expansion without word splitting?

Comment: or just iterate over glob . . . less mess that way

Comment: Is there an command/way to be able to do this on lines with spaces? Maybe replace al " " with "\ " I have no idea how to use glob i know my basics but

Comment: @Marco For a thorough solution, you'd have to escape every character in `$IFS`.

Comment: No, backslashing doesn't work, because it doesn't prevent wordsplitting. Switch to a real programming language where variables are first class citizens, not expanding macros.

Comment: If the glob is *always* a trailing `*`, then couldn't it simply be removed and replaced e.g. `rm -- "${line%\*}"*`?

Comment: I don't know, `a*.php` is a valid glob expression, too.

Comment: for my usage there are no extensions those are the same only the parts that come after the numbers are different

Answer (score 1):

#### Find

If you're only deleting files in the pwd (like in the question), you can replace `rm` with `find -name` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$line"
```

This just outputs filenames that match the glob. If the output looks good, add `-delete` at the end.

---

#### Python

For anything not covered by the `find` solution above, this should work:

```
python3 -c 'import glob, os, sys; [print(f) for f in glob.glob(sys.argv[1])]' "$line"
```

If the output looks good, replace `print` with `os.remove`.

Or you could write the whole script in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
For each line from "fileinput", treat it as a glob and delete
the matching files.
'''

import fileinput
import glob
import os

for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    for file in glob.glob(line):
        # If the output looks good, replace "print" with "os.remove"
        print(file)
```

Though note that if no arguments are given, `fileinput` reads from stdin instead of erroring.